# How to stop Safari 16 (macOS) defaulting to the current date in a HTML type="date" input?

Tags: html, safari

Trying to get Safari date fields to be blank when no date is selected (ie. not default to todays date) but I can't seem to figure it out.

All other browsers do not pre-fill the date field when no date value is given, eg.

```html
<input type="date" />
```

However Safari insists it should display a placeholder like value of todays date.

[image: Greyed out date placeholder1]

Trying to override the placeholder styles like the following does not seem to make any effect:

```css
input[type="data"]::placeholder {
    color: transparent; /* Or any colour/display: none/etc */
}


input[type="data"]:placeholder-shown {
    color: transparent; /* Or any colour/display: none/etc */
}
```

Setting the value to empty string or the likes also has no effect and setting the placeholder value to anything else does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are several psuedo classes available to date fields on webkit browsers. In Safari, to be able to see them, you can inspect the element and go into the shadow root. In the shadow root for the date field you will find div elements with a `psuedo` attribute hinting the available psuedo selectors:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text
```

This allows you to style each part of the date individually. You unfortunately cannot target the placeholder value with `:placeholder-shown`.

Currently, unless I am mistaken, this means it is impossible in Safari 16 on macOS to get rid of the placeholder without some javascript.

What you instead can do is keep track in Javascript using the `onchange` events whether the input has a value and apply a class. This will then let you select the individual elements of the date field using the above psuedo selectors when the class is applied.

For example (in regular html/js):

```html
<style>
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field, 
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field, 
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
        opacity: var(--field-opacity, 0);
    }

    input[type="date"].has-value {
        --field-opacity: 1;
    }
</style>

<input type="date" id="my-date" />
<script>
    const dateField = document.getElementById('my-date');
    dateField.addEventListener('change', (ev) => {
        if (ev.target.value) {
        ev.target.classList.add('has-value');
        } else {
        ev.target.classList.remove('has-value');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Of course you will likely want to make this code reusable in your framework of choice.

Bear in mind this will also hide the placeholders on other browsers. While in most cases this consistency would not be an issue, you may want to do some browser detection to determine whether the hidden placeholders should apply or not.

Comment: Empty value can be detected with CSS only:
```input[type="date"][value=""]```

Comment: @user712092 I did try this previously however editing the field does not update the attribute value therefore it doesn't actually update the styles unfortunately.